# How many transactions per second can blake2s algorithm can handle?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, altcoin, bitcoin-core-development, algorithms

i saw the hash functions speed (miBps) are 947 according to this website: https://blake2.net/

but how many transactions blake2s algorithm can handle? Verge uses the same algorithm right?

more about blake2s
https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/322.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of transactions per second a blockchain can process is not correlated to the relative computational speed of the hashing algorithm.

A faster hashing algorithm just means the network's miners will be able to attempt more hashes per second, given the same (general purpose) hardware.

The number of transactions per second will depend on the block size, transaction size(s), and the average block time.

Comment: thanks for the answer, how can I calculate it in Verge? simple sample for that? thank you.

Comment: @chicolima (megabyte/block) / ((megabyte/avg transaction)*(seconds/block))